# php extension dll in windows

Tags: php, c++, fastcgi

I have following Problem:
I run php as fastcgi (IIS 7.5 windows 2008 R2 64 bit)

Now i write test function "use_html". I compile this dll as php extension (Visual 2012). I copied it to php\ext folder

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "php_ext.h"


//#define PHP_COMPILER_ID  "VC9"

ZEND_FUNCTION(use_html);

zend_function_entry use_functions[] =
{
    ZEND_FE(use_html, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

zend_module_entry use_html_module_entry =
{
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "Use Html",
    use_functions,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    "1.0.0-tutorial",
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

ZEND_GET_MODULE(use_html);

ZEND_FUNCTION(use_html)
{
     //bool useHtml;
     //if(zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "|b", &useHtml) == FAILURE)
     //{
     //    E_ERROR;
     //    return;
     //}
     //if(useHtml)
     //{
         php_printf("This string uses <a href='#'>Html</a>");
     //}
     //else
     //{
     //    php_printf("This string does not Html");
     //}
     return;
}
```

It works if I call phpinfo(); - i see that Use Html extension is insalled; it didn't work if I call a function use_html(true) in php script...

I always get exception from IIS server
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\php-5.4.6-Win32-VC9-x86\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Qouestion: it always has to be compiled with the same compiler version ?? or ??

Comment: Have you added it in php.ini (`extension=php_myExtension.dll`) and restarted IIS?

Comment: HTTP error 500 does not say anything special. Look in the log to see exactly what has happened.

Comment: http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a154/where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx

Comment: Log from my IIS _2012-09-10 12:54:13 ::1 GET /phpinfo.php - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 500 0 255 2745_ . It is possible to activate debug log or something like this?